# signal SIGABRT error when adding google maps to view

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I followed the document on google maps ios sdk site to add a google maps to a viewcontroller. Since I used the storyboard for the viewcontroller that I want to add the map in before, so instead of using the `-(void)loadView` method in the example code, I programmatically add the map view in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //some implementation before add google maps 
    gMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];
    gMapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285 longitude:103.848 zoom:12];
    [self.view addSubView:gMapView];
}
```

But when I step through the code, I got a signal `SIGABRT` error on the line

```
gMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];
```

without any more detail from the debug area. Before, if I got a signal `SIGABRT` error, there are some logs showing in the debugging area helping me find the error, but this time, there is nothing, so I don't really know what's wrong with this line.

Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated!

Comment: copy paste the error log you got...

Comment: @MilKyWaY There is no error log showing in the console pane...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `initWithFrame` to allocate the map view. Instead you should use `mapWithFrame`, as shown in the sample code [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#add_a_map):

```
GMSCameraPosition* camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285 longitude:103.848 zoom:12];
gMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320) camera:camera];
```